# Pillow pasting doesn't overlay correctly

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to merge 2 images together using Pillow. A problem comes when some images have the in itself the same image as the other one, but with transparency (I'll post an example later). Here's the code I'm using:

```
import os, subprocess
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter

# Creates card art
rootdir = os.listdir('C:/Users/amati/Desktop/Dokkan Assets/japan/character/card')
for entries in rootdir:
    newdir = 'C:/Users/amati/Desktop/Dokkan Assets/japan/character/card/' + str(entries)
    bg = newdir + '/' + 'card_' + str(entries) + '_bg.png'
    effect = newdir + '/' + 'card_' + str(entries) + '_effect.png'
    
    try:
        image1 = Image.open(bg)
        image3 = Image.open(effect)
        
        rgbimage1 = image1.convert('RGBA')
        rgbimage3 = image3.convert('RGBA')
        
        image1_size = rgbimage1.size
        
        final = Image.new('RGBA',(image1_size[0], image1_size[1]), (0,0,0,255))
        final.paste(rgbimage1,(0,0))
        final.paste(rgbimage3,(0,0),rgbimage3)
        
        if not os.path.exists('C:/Users/amati/Desktop/prova/card_' + str(entries) + '.png'):
            final.save('C:/Users/amati/Desktop/prova/card_' + str(entries) + '.png', quality = 95)
    except IOError:
        continue
```

Images:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLo6c.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7O0X.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoBsf.png)

[Expected result using Paint 3D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJHJN.png)

Comment: Please provide the code you tried. Loading the first image, it has [mode](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html?highlight=Modes#modes) `P`, i.e. it has an image palette. On the other hand, the second image has mode `RGBA`. When convertig the first one to `RGBA` also, the alpha channel has some gradual transparency. How did you take that into account when building the expected image using "an image tool" (which one?)?

Comment: @HansHirse updated with the code, hope it's clearer now